# Полная очистка локальных коммитов

Tags: git, git-commit, git-pull, git-reset

есть такой вопрос: как сбросить все локальные коммиты и заново скачать их с сервера? Файлы должны быть тоже удалены.

Comment: Вам нужна абсолютно полная очистка коммитов, не попавших на сервер? Из всех возможных ваших веток?

Comment: Именно, можно только ветку master брать

Comment: Git clone с сервера

Comment: @KAGGDesign git clone создаст новую папку, что мне не нужно

Comment: А что вам нужно? Удалите все файлы и папку, сделайте git clone снова

Comment: @KAGGDesign Уже нашел решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел способ как это все сделать:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Команда `git fetch` загружает последнюю версию файлов из удаленного репозитория, не пытаясь что-либо объединить или синхронизировать (`merge` или `rebase`)

А команда `git reset` назначает главной веткой ту, которую вы только что обновили. Опция `--hard` изменяет все файлы в вашей рабочей ветке в соответствии с файлами в `origin/master`

Comment: То же самое, что грохнуть все и сделать Git clone

Comment: @KAGGDesign Иногда не удобно удалять всю папку и заного ее качать. У Вас не самый лучший и безопасный вариант для моего проекта.

Comment: Не самый лучший - только в плане скорости. Fetch будет быстрее. По результату - одно и то же. По безопасности - это о чем вообще?